# large-size page-locked memory copy get wrong result in CUDA

Tags: memory-management, cuda

I found an issue about large-size page-locked memory in CUDA. Here is the source code and makefile. The code allocates 10GB page-locked memory and copy some data from device memory to this page-locked memory, the data in device memory are set 1.0 before the copy.

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "helper_cuda.h"

__global__ 
void test_k(double* x, size_t n)
{
    int gid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if(gid<n) x[gid] = 1.0 ;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    size_t n = size_t(10)*1024*1024*1024/sizeof(double);
    printf("\n n: %zu, page-locked memory size: %zu MB\n", n, n*sizeof(double)/1024/1024);
    double* x_h = NULL, *x_d = NULL;

    int gpuid = 0;
    if(argc>1 ) gpuid = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf("select gpu %d\n", gpuid);
    checkCudaErrors(cudaSetDevice(gpuid));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocHost(&x_h, sizeof(double)*n));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&x_d, sizeof(double)*n));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) x_h[i]=0.0;

    int nthd = 256;
    int nblk = (n+nthd-1) / nthd;
    test_k<<<nblk, nthd, 0, 0>>>(x_d, n);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(x_h, x_d, sizeof(double)*n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    int errCount = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        if(x_h[i] == 0.0) errCount++;
    }
    printf("%s errCount: %d, which should be 0\n", errCount?"Error:":"Correct", errCount);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(x_d));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFreeHost(x_h));
    return 0;
}
```

```
CUDA_PATH = /depot/cuda/cuda-11.2/
CUDA_INC = -I$(CUDA_PATH)/include -I$(CUDA_PATH)/samples/common/inc
NVCC = $(CUDA_PATH)/bin/nvcc
NVCCXXFLAGS = -std=c++11 -O3 -w -m64 -Xptxas -dlcm=cg -gencode=arch=compute_70,code=sm_70 -gencode=arch=compute_80,code=sm_80 $(CUDA_INC) 
all: testLargePin

testLargePin: testLargePin.cu
    $(NVCC) $^ $(NVCCXXFLAGS) -o $@

clean:
    rm testLargePin -f
```

I run the binary on three different GPU servers(all with A100-SXM4-40GB). On machine 1, the result is correct. On machine 2, it reports

```
CUDA error at testLargePin.cu:31 code=719(cudaErrorLaunchFailure) "cudaMemcpy(x_h, x_d, sizeof(double)*n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)"
```

On machine 3, its copy is wrong, there are lots of zeros in the page-locked array.

```
 n: 1342177280, page-locked memory size: 10240 MB
select gpu 0
Error: errCount: 1024, which should be 0
```

Anyone knows the reason and how to fix the issue? like an API to check the max page-locked memory size in specified machine? Thanks in advance.

Comment: We fix the wrong result on machine 3 by turning off iommu. The CPU model on that machine is AMD EPYC 73F3.

Answer (score 1):

By NVIDIA, (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__TYPES.html#group__CUDA__TYPES_1gc6c391505e117393cc2558fff6bfc2e9)

Error 719 is about dereferencing an invalid device pointer, accessing out of bounds shared memory, or system specific problem...

In my experience, synchronization helped troubles about memory error and inconsistent results. Did you try adding `cudaDeviceSyncronize();` after `checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(x_h, x_d, sizeof(double)*n, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));` ??

About page-locked memory, there's no limit in CUDA. I think you have to check this on your host side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added cudaDeviceSyncronize() but there is no change. As for as I known, it is not necessary to add cudaDeviceSyncronize() after cudaMemcpy. 
As for the issue in my post, I guess it is related to OS or CPU. I have no idea how to figure out.